# Angular Ionic 3 form builder custom validator does not work in type email but works in type of text

Tags: angular, validation, email, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an **Ionic 3 App** where I use [formBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) for all of my **forms** in the **App**. I created a custom validator that wouldn't allowed spaces in an input type of **email** field in some **forms**.

I will show first the code then I will explain it after each code block.

Here is my code in the **custom validator function**

```
noSpaceValidator(control: FormControl) {
    let isWhitespace = control.value.includes(" ");
    let isValid = !isWhitespace;
    return isValid ? null : { 'spaces': true }
  }
```

So the function is very simple that if the value includes **spaces**. It wouldn't allow the form to be valid and display some error message that I created.

Now in my **formBuilder** below

```
email: [
        "",
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.pattern(EMAIL_REGEX),
          Validators.required,
          this.noSpaceValidator
        ])
      ],
```

I called the `noSpacesValidator` function which is working fine but only in the type of **text**.

In my **html**

```
<ion-input type="email" formControlName="email">
```

This is very simple **html** but there is a little small problem when using the type **email**. When using type **email** the `noSpaceValidator` function still does get called but it doesn't return a the custom validator. But when I try to replace it with `type="text"` the it returns the custom validator.

I wanted to work with **email** since I am building a **mobile app** so it would always suggest **cached emails** on the **Android device** and for the auto completion feature of **type email**.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you check that it is called or not? If you set `email` as input, browser may do additional checks, like trim spaces, ensure that input matches email address format and then pass to the application. Then all your validators may just execute and return `valid`.

Comment: @muradm sorry I edited the question. You are right that the function is still being called but it doesn't return the expected valid format for that field. If that's the case then how would I work on it? I stil want to use the email type tho.

Comment: By using type="email" , by default it would also check for spaces , so I don't think you need to write another custom validator just to check for spaces.
But i did use a custom validator called blank spaces along with type="email" and both of them work.
Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-validation-rezaja

Comment: @kirtipriya it does not validate the space at the beginning for example I type 
" sample@example.com". But when I type "ssample sample@sample.com" it validates the space.

Comment: type="email" will remove the leading and trailing spaces